# remove string: 'custom content...' from every page

Tags: html, content

I'm not quite sure how this came about, but every page on my site has the text 'custom content...' appended to the end of the body. The string appears within `<p>` tags on the frontend.

I've searched in ubuntu for that string in the directory but none of the results seem to be the explanation. I've also opened and scanned files like `page.php`,`footer.php`, `header.php` but it doesn't seem to be in there. How might I remove this (without hiding via css)?

it also does not appear in the wordpress html editor.

Comment: It may be introduced by some plugin. De-activate all plugins one by one to find the culprit. If it is alive site, share the link.

Comment: Sounds like a plugin or theme issue, not a content (DB) problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a custom plug-in that I was following in a tutorial but abandoned a long time ago and left active.

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: After 2 days, mark your answer as **Accepted Answer** to help others searching for similar issue.